# unity lag while running to builds or two editors

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, network-programming, instance, lag

So I am trying to test out multiplayer for my unity game. Anytime I run two builds, my fps in the unfocused build drops down to 20FPS which makes it exptremely hard to test stuff. Before starting the second instance, I get 120ish fps. I have made sure to disable Vsync, turn on run in background, manually, checked my GPU software for vsync, and changed various windows settings.

In the profile the  Gfx.WaitForPresent does spike and I have researched multiple solutions to this with just nothing working. I am hoping someone has a solution.

Unity Version: 2022.3.12f1

I have done countless hours of digging for a solution and i'm just tired of it so I am using this as a last resort.